# Unable to Update PHP Version

Tags: php, wamp

Current environment:
WAMP 2.4 (PHP5.4.16),
Expectation:  upgrade PHP Version from 5.4.16 to 5.5.26.
Getting Following Error: [image]

While switching the php version, getting below error

[image]

Comment: maybe apache needs an update?

Comment: http://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/

Comment: @DeepKakkar yes i followed these REF URL steps and finally i met the version conflic problem

Comment: then better to upgrade wamp server version. as Rajat suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your WAMP version to latest 2.5, it will automatically upgrade your apache version to be compatible with latest php version.

Comment: See these notes on how to install a new WAMPServer version without loosing anything from your current install. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606